# Python pdfminer.six hangs

Tags: python, pdfminer

My script works fine to extract text from pdf files except for some files that have some pages with table figures that are flipped clockwise while still in portrait mode.

Sorry I can't post the pdf file as it's condfidential. Greatly appreciate some resolution on this.

I'm running on windows 7 64-bit

```
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
sio = StringIO()
codec = 'utf-8'
laparams = LAParams()
device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, sio, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
try:
    f = open(r"myfile.pdf", "rb")
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(f):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    out_str = sio.getvalue()
    f.close()
    device.close()
    sio.close()
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
    out_str = None

print(out_str)
```